# how to setup tomcat and eclipse for centralized evironment

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I have a linux server where tomcat server is installed I can access it by http://omx.td.com:8080 from my LAN. I have 20 computers in LAN and 16 developer for a enterprise project which is deployed on that tomcat server. In each machine eclipse is installed.

I want my developers will work on that project not creating any local instance of tomcat or I dont want local project like every machine should be installed with tomcat.

Can anyone please help me how to setup this centralized environment ?

I have tried with eclipse remote debug on tomcat but no luck.

I want my developers should update on the same single server.

Please help !!!

Thanks

Comment: IMHO it is not a good idea to have everyone working concurrently on 1 tomcat instance. People have created things like SVN so that you have a common test base where everyone can work on different things and test independently of other people's changes. This is not going to be possible on your single tomcat implementation

Answer (score 0):

While I concur with user1291492 about source control, you had specific requirements.  In each developer's eclipse machine,

Click Window/Show View/Servers

Right-click in the servers pane (window):
New/Server

From the List, click on Apache, then click on the tomcat that's on the server.

For server's host name, type the ip address of the server.

Comment: I have tried it but the problem to update on the remote code base. I have tried it but no luck. It is throwing resource not found error.

Comment: in eclipse it is not supported the remote host error message it is showing.